# Average Coverage Error (ACE)

Tags: confidence-interval, forecasting, quantiles, prediction-interval

This [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.01720v1.pdf) mentions ACE. It is defined as following

> ACE = PICP - PINC

where PICP and PINC stand for Prediction Interval Coverage Probability and Prediction Interval Nominal Confidence, respectively.

The [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.01720v1.pdf) states that ACE should be as close to zero as possible. Let's assume PICP has a coverage probability close to one for a confidence interval 0.95. PINC would equal to .05.

So, I don't see, or rather agree, why ACE should be close to zero. Could someone explain why?

Comment: Can you tell us why you don't agree?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen For the case with the above numbers, it can only be close to zero if PICP is close to zero. But a low PICP would indicate that the correct value is not in the prediction interval. Therefore a low PICP is not preferred. So, why should ACE be close to zero?